# Difference, in graphic cards memory, between NIVIDA official page and laptop specifications

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, memory

I'm inspecting NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050. According to [the NVIDIA official web](https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/graphics-cards/30-series/rtx-3050/), this card has  8GB memory. However, some laptops that state have this card, also say it has 4 GB. For instance, [HP Victus 15](https://www.hp.com/gb-en/shop/product.aspx?id=6P128EA&opt=ABU&sel=NTB). I have inspected some of those NVIDIA itself advertises (see [this list](https://store.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/store/laptop/?page=1&limit=9&locale=en-gb&gpu=RTX%203050&category=LAPTOP&category_filter=GPU%7E0,LAPTOP%7E0,STUDIO-LAPTOP%7E0,DESKTOP%7E0,MONITOR%7E0)), and the same happens.

So does the RTX3050 have 4GB or 8 GB? If the mentioned card has 2 versions, is there any laptop finder that allows to specify how many graphic card's GB I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The RTX 3050 *mobile* has either 4 GB or 6 GB of VRAM depending on your variant. The *desktop* version has 8 GB of VRAM. The 4 GB variant of the RTX 3050 mobile is also substantially slower.

It's fair to say Nvidia's graphics card marketing names suck. To make a long story short, laptop graphics cards and desktop graphics cards generally aren't the same—i.e. an RTX 3080 (desktop) is not the same chip as a RTX 3080 (laptop), and won't perform the same. Even if they were the same chip, modern GPUs are typically power and thermal limited; thus, in a laptop, any GPU can only perform as well as that laptop's cooling allows it. The TL;DR of this is that the only reliable benchmark for laptop GPU performance is... a benchmark of that specific laptop with that specific GPU. Which sucks, and is crazy confusing for consumers, but that's where we've ended up.

That said, we can at least get a vague benchmark by comparing what hardware is in each laptop; generally, the easiest way to do this is by looking at GPU chip code names, such as [this Wikipedia table for the GeForce 30 series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_30_series#Laptop)

As you can see, the GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop always uses a GA107 chip (the same as [*some*, but not *all* desktop RTX 3050s](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/nvidia-geForce-rtx-3050-uses-ga106-silicon), but that's another can of worms.) However, where the desktop card comes with 8 GB of VRAM, the mobile version can come with *either* 4 GB of 6 GB of VRAM. Even more confusingly, the 4 GB version of the card *is also a slower version of the GA107 chip*, with fewer CUDA cores and stream processors. Eesh.

Anyways, all this to say: despite having the same name, they're not the same really. It's marketing. **The best we can do is provide you with a more specific laptop recommendation, given your budget and your needs.** If you can edit your post with this information, we can help you better.